Is 2 Thessalonians 2:3 when it says 'that day' obviously refer to verse 1 or not?
2 Thessalonians 2:3 NIV 1987
DON’T LET ANYONE DECEIVE YOU IN ANY WAY, for that day [=‘the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ & our being gathered to him (2 Thes.2:1)] will not come until the rebellion occurs & the man of lawlessness is revealed, proclaiming himself to be God.

It is clear what Paul meant when the previous two verses are considered. Here is how a literal translation renders those verses:

"And we ask you, brethren, in regard to the presence of our Lord Jesus
Christ, and of our gathering together unto him, that ye be not quickly
shaken in mind, nor be troubled, neither through spirit, neither
through word, neither through letters as through us, as that the day
of Christ hath arrived; let not anyone deceive you in any manner,
because - if the falling away may not come first, and the man of sin
be revealed - the son of the destruction, who is opposing and is
raising himself up above all called God or worshipped, so that he in
the sanctuary of God as God hath sat down, shewing himself off that he
is God - [the day doth not come]." 2 Thessalonians 2:1-4 Young's
Literal Translation

Verse 1 speaks of the day of the Lord, when he returns in glory to present himself to his people, to gather them together to be with him.
Verse 2 warns of others speaking or writing words, as though with the apostle's authority, to lead them astray into thinking that day had arrived.
Verse 3 warns that, before that day comes, there will be a falling away from the true faith.
Verse 4 enlarges on that: a diabolical attempt to usurp God's sovereign place, to deceive people into thinking this 'man of sin, the son of destruction' is actually God and to be worshipped as such.
The final point is that "that day of the Lord" will not come until those other events have happened, prior to Christ's return.
So, yes, the answer is that the day in verse 3 is exactly the same day as in verse 1 - the spectacular Day of the Lord, when he returns in glory for his own.

In 2 Thess 2:3, "that day" is a phrase used by NIV, NLT, ESV, KJV, NKJV, CSB, HCSB, GWT, NET, WBT, WNT, etc.
However, "that day" is a helpful interpretation by these versions that does not appear in the Greek.  Here is my overly literal translation of the Greek:

No one should deceive you in any way because it is not until the
apostacy comes first, and the man of lawlessness is revealed, the son
of destruction.

The Greek is terse and tricky to properly render into nuanced English (the Greek verb forms have no parallel in English).  However, that V3 alludes to that which comes immediately before (vis V1 & 2) is undoubtedly true.  V3 is discussing the great deception that must occur BEFORE the Lord returns in the great Eschaton.
APPENDIX - Eschatological Deception
The Bible has much more to say about deception in the last days than in the Christian life generally, suggesting that towards the end, deception will greatly increase.  That is, eschatological deception is simply deception that rises to a crescendo just before the second advent of Jesus.  There are several apocalyptic passages that discuss this important subject.

The Synoptic Apocalypse contains two warnings about false messiahs (or christs) in Matt 24:4, 5, 23, 24, Mark 13:6, Luke 21:8.  Specifically, such false christs will use lying signs and wonders to deceive.  Compare 2 Peter 2.
“Paul’s Apocalypse” of 2 Thess 2 contains an extended discussion about the work of Satan in the last days.  Satan is prophesied to stand in God’s Temple (the church according to 1 Cor 3:16, 17); however, he will only deceive those who have “refused to receive the love of the truth” (v10).  Again, the chosen instrument is lying signs and wonders to which the righteous are immune.
In 1 Thess 4:1-3 we also learn about the rise of false teachers who are liars and hypocrites because they deceive people by forbidding marriage and selected foods .
2 Tim 3:1-9 predicts a rising flood of sinful and depraved people who are self-absorbed, self-centered, etc, etc.
“Peter’s Apocalypse” in 2 Peter 3 predicts the rise of the doctrine of uniformitarianism (v3-6) or “Evolution” as it is now popularly known.  Few ideas have had a more corrosive effect on Christianity than Evolution because they demote God from His position as creator (Ps 33:6, 9) and sustainer (Col 1:15-17).
John’s Apocalypse (Revelation) also contains similar warnings.  Rev 13:13-16 predicts the rise of a power that gives breath or spirit to an image and deceives using lying signs and wonders.
Rev 9 (5th and 6th trumpets) also predicts a similar phenomenon of signs and wonders used to deceive the wicked in order to keep people worshiping false gods and demons (v20, 21).  Again, note that whatever we make of these trumpets, they perfectly distinguish between the righteous and wicked because only the wicked fall victim to the plagues and are deceived.
The sixth plague of Rev 16:12-14, 16 provides even more detail but in highly symbolic form.  The waters of the Euphrates River are died up (compare Rev 17:15).  This is followed by three evil/unclean spirits from the mouths of the dragon, (sea) beast, and false prophet, or Beast Trinity.  These three evil spirits perform lying miracles to deceive the wicked of the earth and are clearly counterpoints to the three messengers/angels of Rev 14:6-11.  The three evil spirits gather kings for the great battle of (H)Armageddon (Rev 16:16).  Let us observe several things about this scene:


(a)    The battle of Armageddon is described in Rev 17:12-14 and Rev 19:11-21.  It occurs between the kings of the earth and the armies of heaven “dressed in fine linen, white and clean” (Rev 19:14), that is, the righteous of earth (v8).




(b)    The weapons of war are: for the wicked – lying signs spirits from the mouths of the Beast Trinity; for the righteous – the sword from the mouth of Jesus (compare Rev 1:16).




(c)    The “evil spirits like frogs” is a clear reference to the second plague of Ex 8:5-7.  Note that while Pharaoh’s magicians could replicate this plague, they could not replicate any further miracles/plagues sent by God.  This, the deception of the plague of frogs by Egypt’s magicians, was the last deception.


While false prophets and teachers have always existed, they will become far more numerous in the last days and at the end of time (Matt 7:15, 24:11, 24, Mark 13:22, Luke 6:26, 2 Tim 4:3, 4, 2 Thess 2:1-12, Rev 13:13-16, 19:21, 20:10) often using lying signs and wonders.  (Recent history confirms this.)
2 Cor 11:12-14 even predicts that Satan will stage the ultimate deception by appearing near the end of time as an angel of light!

These numerous Biblical warnings against deceptions are for the righteous, who, as long as they persevere, are immune.  Therefore, deception warnings are another warning to the righteous to persevere.  The Christian perseveres by “fixing our eyes on Jesus” (Heb 12:2), “having the mind of Christ” (1 Cor 2:16), and “contemplating the Lord’s glory” (2 Cor 3:18), etc.  That is, continuing to imitate Jesus.

Look at several other translations and the intended meaning should become clearer.
For instance, the New Living Translation has 2 Thessalonians 2:1–4 as:

1 Now, dear brothers and sisters, let us clarify some things about the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ and how we will be gathered to meet him.
2 Don’t be so easily shaken or alarmed by those who say that the day of the Lord has already begun. Don’t believe them, even if they claim to have had a spiritual vision, a revelation, or a letter supposedly from us.
3 Don’t be fooled by what they say. For that day will not come until there is a great rebellion against God and the man of lawlessness is revealed—the one who brings destruction.
4 He will exalt himself and defy everything that people call god and every object of worship. He will even sit in the temple of God, claiming that he himself is God.


Paul says he his going to make the details of Christ's return clearer, and what must happen before the saints are converted into immortal spirit beings.
He tells the people not to believe any reports they might hear from others about the end-times having already started or be afraid that Christ did not welcome you.
He tells them that there will be obvious signs that will precede the event.
The most obvious sign will the appearance of a powerful religious leader that will blatantly disobey God's way of life and will eventually declare himself to be God.

